# Group into Years and Type using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset (Data):

**(Data)**

```
Quarter Type  Value
1989-Q1 A      3.8
1989-Q1 B      3.9
1989-Q2 A      3.7
1989-Q2 B      3.2
1989-Q3 A      4.2
1989-Q3 B      4.2
1989-Q4 A      4.1
1989-Q4 B      4.5
1990-Q1 A      4.8
1990-Q1 B      4.9
1990-Q2 A      4.7
1990-Q2 B      4.2
1990-Q3 A      4.6
1990-Q3 B      4.7
1990-Q4 A      4.8
```

I would like to use pandas to group the quarters into year for each of the type (Desired)

**(Desired)**

```
Quarter
1989 A 3.9  # (Average of the 4 Quarters)
1990 A 3.7
1989 B 3.7  # (Average of the 4 Quarters)
1990 B 3.6
```

Please advise how this can be achieved. Tq

Comment: Please format correctly!

Comment: So sorry! I did realize the format went awry! Have amended it. Tq for informing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course by the time I'd finished this others had gotten there first, but I did add a sort at the end:

```
df['Year'], df['Quarter'] = df['Quarter'].str.split('-', 1).str
df = df[['Year', 'Type', 'Value']]
grp = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Year', 'Type'])['Value'].mean())
grp.sort_values(by='Type')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to calculate averages of `Value` per `Year` and `Type`. Since your data doesn't have a column with data of years you first need to get this from the `Quarter` column.

One way of doing it is to [`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html).

```
df[["Year", "Quarter"]] = df['Quarter'].str.split('-', expand=True)
```

Now we can calculate averages by using [`DataFrame.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df.groupby(['Year', 'Type'])['Value'].mean()
```

Comment: Thanks! I ll try it out. Thanks again :)